# Python, speed up regex expression for extracting sub strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text

```
text = "This is a string with C1234567 and CM123456, CM123, F1234567 and also M1234, M123456"
```

And I would like to extract this list of substrings

```
['C1234567', 'CM123456', 'F1234567']
```

This is what I came up with

```
new_string = re.compile(r'\b(C[M0-9]\d{6}|[FM]\d{7})\b')
new_string.findall(text)
```

However, I was wondering if there's a way to do this faster since I'm interested in performing this operation tens of thousands of times.

I thought I could use `^` to match the beginning of string, but the regex expression I came up with

```
new_string = re.compile(r'\b(^C[M0-9]\d{6}|^[FM]\d{7})\b')
```

Doesn't return anything anymore. I know this is a very basic question, but I'm not sure how to use the `^` properly.

Comment: The regex looks good. If you are interested in performance, use `grep`, not `Python`

Comment: Well, to tell the truth, the pattern is already optimized. The match only starts at a word boundary, and then there are 2 alternative branches that do not match at the same location - which means it is great. You might try and replace your pattern with [`\b[CF][M0-9]\d{6}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/1fbLR7/2/), but it will match `FM123456`, which is not the case with your regex.

Comment: Well, that regex in my comment above won't match `M0123456`, so your regex is the best so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good and bad news.  Bad news, regex looks pretty good, going to be hard to improve.  Good news, I have some ideas :)  I would try to do a little outside the box thinking if you are looking for performance.  I do Extract Transform Load work, and a lot with Python.

- You are already doing the re.compile (big help)
- The regex engine is left to right, so short circuit where you can.  Doesn't seem to apply here
- If you have a big chunk of data that you are going to be looping over multiple times, clean it up front ONCE of stuff you KNOW won't match.  Think of an HTML page, you only want stuff in HEAD stuff to get HEAD and need to run loops of many regexes over that section.  Extract that section, only do that section, not the whole page.  Seems obvious, isn't always :)
- Use some metrics, give cProfile a try.  Maybe there is some logic around where you are regexing that you can speed up.  At least you can find your bottleneck, maybe the regex isn't the problem at all.